# Please use the office closet and/or coat rack to hang your coat

Tags: company-culture

I have staff that refuses to use the closet and/or coat rack to hang their coats.  Instead they hang then over the cubical and/or their desk chairs.  How can I get them to change this habit?

Comment: I guess you need to do a better job of defining why this is an issue worth making a fuss over than you did in your question.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: Does your office cloak room have an attendant that will keep people from going through my coat pockets and/or borrowing my coat without permission? Do I have to walk a significant distance to get my coat before I can go outside? Do I have to walk past your office to hang up/retrieve my coat so you can keep track of my comings and goings? I can think of lots of reasons folks may prefer to keep their coats in their cube and not many ways that not using the coat rack would negatively affect productivity.

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: How many people who are allergic to animals will go home sneezing after they put on their coat that was hanging next to my jacket that is covered in cat hair?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of aspects you'll need to address before you can get them to change.

1. You'll need to explain the business reasons for why this is important, and the consequences of not using the supplied coat racks.
2. You'll need to have a way to assure them that anything left in pockets, as well as the coats themselves will be as secure as when they are kept in eyesight by the employees.

If there is no good reason other than personal preference, then you'll need strong consequences to enforce this (and may loose good employees).  If you can make them see a good reason for this (looks better to customers?), you'll have a better buy-in.

Comment: Agreed I am more likely to start leaving my coat in my car to avoid having to use the coat rack.

Comment: @Chad - You obviously do not live in Scotland. The coat is essential this time of year to get yourself from the car to to office front door without getting wet.

Comment: @EdHeal That goes double for Canada.

Answer (score 0):

That depends upon the situation, which you have left undefined.

1. SUDDEN STOP - If there has been a long standing policy of requiring people to hang their coats in a closet and suddenly now your staff has stopped doing that, then you need to find out **WHY** they've stopped and address it.
2. TREASURE HUNT - If this is some obscure policy that you happened to find on a rules and regulation treasure hunt, and desire to enforce it, then you can force it as a direct order, but without a valid, logical reason, you'll likely lose the respect of your staff.
3. GOOD REASON - If there is a good reason - such as staff areas routinely have customers as visitors and your company desires to project a good clean image, then you explain that reason to your employees and state that it will be enforced.  They may not like it, but they won't think you're an idiot either as there is a good reason for it.
4. YOU ARE NEW - If you are new to your role as a manager and are trying to enforce company policy, then you need to ask yourself if this is a battle worth fighting.  If they've never done it before under the prior manager, then making them do it now will cause you to lose respect and gain you and the company nothing.

Answer (score -1):

(a) Why don't the employees use the coat rack? And (b) Why do you care?

If people don't use the coat rack because several coats have been stolen, I'd say that's a good reason. Or if it's because the coat rack is on the opposite side of the building and they don't want to go that far to drop off and pick up their coats, that's understandable.

Whatever the reasons are, is there something you can do to address them? Like move the coat rack to a more convenient location? Post armed guards to protect the coats? Etc.

But why do you care? Is it just that you think it looks sloppy? If that's all it is -- and frankly I'm hard-pressed to think of another reason -- is that important enough to make a big deal about? If you're the boss, I presume you could declare that this is company policy and anyone who hangs a coat over the partition will be penalized in some way. But unless the employees see a justification for this, I think it will just cause resentment.

If there's really an issue, like the coats are regularly falling off the partitions and landing in the hallways and then people are tripping over them, or something of that sort, then explain the reason and see if you don't get some co-operation.

But if it's just your personal preference about neatness, and especially if you're not the boss, I think the only answer is to quit worrying about it. There are plenty of things people do around the office that I don't like. For example, I don't like people wearing blue jeans to work, I think it's inappropriate. But I'm not going to say anything about it, because it's not worth annoying somebody for a trivial issue.

Comment: This is basically a big rant against the question and does not attempt to help the OP find an answer to their problem.

Comment: Jay - have an upvote from me. This was exactly my thinking. I never use a coat rack (unless one is provided next to my desk) as I don't want to have my coat somewhere I can't see

Comment: @chad Maybe so. But I think that sometimes the best answer to a question of "how do I do X" is to say, "doing X is a bad idea". If someone posted, "I hate my boss. How can I murder him?", would you insist that any attempt to dissuade the OP from murdering his boss is invalid and non-responsive, and the only good answers are those that discuss how best to insure his death and conceal the evidence from the police?

Comment: @Jay - Well as long as it contains a if you insist on murdering your boss the best way is poisoning their lunch(or some other method that actually answers the question).  It is not enough to say you shouldnt, it should include a here is how you should if you insist.

Comment: @Chad I do think this answer has some advice pertinent to the question, although it's a little indirect. Figure out why the staff isn't using the coat racks. Without this information, there's no other reasonable advice to give.

Comment: Sometimes the only meaningful answer to a question is to challenge the premise. To assert that we must accept any premise and answer accordingly is, to my mind, just absurd. Suppose someone asked, "As it is against the law in America to pay an employee for more than 40 hours per week, how can I reward my employees who work overtime?" Would you really insist that pointing out that there is no such law is invalid and non-responsive, and the only valid answers are those that discuss alternative compensation? Ditto for less obvious flawed premises.

Comment: @Jay that is not how this site works.  This is a Q&A site not a forum where you are free to debate the concepts.  Someone has a problem, they need people to start using the coat room.  you do not know why that is there problem(which is a problem with the question) but the assumption needs to be that there is a valid reason and the answer should include how to accomplish this goal.  If you can not then best to pass on answering the question.

Comment: Also [Meta] exists for debating the validity of a question as well ans the ability to vote to close the question if you feel it does not meet site criteria.

Comment: There's already a Meta question on this. http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/when-asked-how-can-i-foo-the-bar-is-dont-foo-the-bar-an-appropriate-answer/3458#3458 Perhaps that's a better place for further discussion. I see you already have an answer there, and I just added my own.